# CSS: Change font color by hover effect

Tags: html, css

I know it's probably an easy question but how can I change my font color in a hover effect? So if I try it my font color doesn't change when I go with my mouse over it.

```
nav ul li:hover {
 background-color:#ffffff;
 color: #000000;
}
```

EDIT: Hey guys thanks for your answer! The solution was:

```
a:hover{color:#000000};
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: post your html code also

Comment: If you accept one of the suggested answers (click the tick under the vote count) you'll gain a few extra rep :)

Comment: Of course I do..I was away sry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one

```
 li a:hover { background-color: green; }
```

Answer (score 1):

if your font is under in `<a href`  then plz try by this way

```
nav ul li a:hover {
 background-color:#ffffff;
 color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
li:hover {
    color: red;
}
</style>


<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>hi</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
nav:hover, ul:hover, li:hover{
 background-color:#ffffff;
 color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nav ul li:hover a{
  background:#fff;
  color:#000;
}
```